# Ubuntu 14.04. kde-services on Dolphin

Tags: 14.04, services, dolphin

Although I do not use Dolphin as the default file manager for Ubuntu, in fact I use it a lot. I find it is very useful and practical. I was thinking about enhancing its functionalities and I found this package that apparently adds a lot of things to Dolphin.

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/kde-services/files/RPM/
```

So, the question is: Do you know how to install this in Ubuntu, and even more important, should I expect a big mess with dependencies. In other words, does it make sense even try it?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
Thank you,
Javier

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and at a first glance it looks like it worked:

```
sudo alien --to-deb --scripts --verbos kde-services-2.0-6.fc21.noarch.rpm
sudo dpkg -i kde-services_2.0-7_all.deb
```